# After migrating from Delphi 10.4 to 11.1, android service does not start anymore

Tags: android, delphi, service

My application runs fine with Delphi 10.4.
I migrated to Delphi 11.1.
Now, I get this when the activity tries to start the android service :

```
04-22 14:22:29.476: W/company.Project(28861): CheckJNI: method to register "dispatchToNative2" not in the given class. This is slow, consider changing your RegisterNatives calls.
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861): ----- class 'Lcom/embarcadero/services/ProjectSvcProxyInterface;' cl=0x13313888 -----
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):   objectSize=188 (172 from super)
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):   access=0x0008.0001
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):   super='java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>' (cl=0x0)
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):   interfaces (1):
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):      0: java.lang.Class<java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler> (cl=0x0)
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):   vtable (4 entries, 11 in super):
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):      0: java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.ProjectSvcProxyInterface.CreateProxyClass(java.lang.Class, long)
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):      1: void com.embarcadero.services.ProjectSvcProxyInterface.cleanNative(long)
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):      2: java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.ProjectSvcProxyInterface.dispatchToNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], long)
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):      3: java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.ProjectSvcProxyInterface.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[])
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):   direct methods (1 entries):
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):      0: void com.embarcadero.services.ProjectSvcProxyInterface.<init>()
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):   instance fields (1 entries):
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861):      0: long com.embarcadero.services.ProjectSvcProxyInterface.pointer
    04-22 14:22:29.476: E/company.Project(28861): Failed to register native method com.embarcadero.services.ProjectSvcProxyInterface.dispatchToNative2(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; in /data/app/~~YUhiWNL9a1_eFqz34FPS8Q==/fr.company.Project-1Kiklfayuhf-wIP9ug-n6Q==/base.apk
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI RegisterNatives called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/embarcadero/services/ProjectSvcProxyInterface;.dispatchToNative2(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;"
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreateNative(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String) (ProxyService.java:-2)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreate(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String) (ProxyService.java:51)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void com.embarcadero.services.ProjectSvc.onCreate() (ProjectSvc.java:40)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:4936)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:310)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:2296)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at boolean android.os.Looper.loopOnce(android.os.Looper, long, int) (Looper.java:226)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:313)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:8633)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:567)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1133)
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579] 
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]     in call to RegisterNatives
    04-22 14:22:29.477: A/company.Project(28861): java_vm_ext.cc:579]     from void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreateNative(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
    04-22 14:22:29.660: A/company.Project(28861): runtime.cc:669] Runtime aborting...
    04-22 14:22:29.660: A/company.Project(28861): runtime.cc:669] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held
```

Migration required some adjustments like using "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" in manifest file, or some code change about permissions as funtion prototypes changed. However this is the same application. I can't find anything about this kind of error.

The application uses the last release of Kastri which is compatible with Delphi 11.

I try to run the application on an physical android 12 device.

Comment: The solution was posted by Dave Nottage here: (https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/HowTo/tree/main/Solutions/AndroidServiceDelphi111)

Comment: Thanks Freddie, it's fixed. The java file generated for the service (ProxyInterface.java) indeed declares a method named dispatchToNative while executable try to call dispatchToNative2. After deleting java template, the right method dispatchToNative2 is declared.

Comment: Delphi 11 was released with quite a few Android changes. But the release notes didn't mention them.